# Checking for a throw new Error with should.js and Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, should.js

I've got an error thrown like so:

```
if (somethingBadHappened) {
    throw new Error('what were you thinking, batman?')
}
```

Now I want to write a test to check that this throws when expected:

```
should(MyClass.methodThatShouldThrow()).throws('what were you thinking, batman?')
```

But that actually throws the error. What am I doing wrong? Should.js docs are pretty light, since it inherits from `assert.throws`, but even the docs for that doesn't work in the 'should.js' way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you had found out, your code execute the function which throws the error & `should` doesn't get a chance to catch it.

To allow proper assertion, you need to wrap the function call in an anonymous function.

```
should(function ()  {MyClass.methodThatShouldThrow();} ).throw('what were you thinking, batman?')
```

Comment: Hrm, ok except I'm getting `undefined is not a function`

Comment: AH, `throw` not `throws`.

Comment: And if you are using es2015, then it will more compact with arrow function for the anon function